# Which group are you in/on? (AmE usage)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

I know that it's usually "on team" in AmE. So is it the same with "group". Like if I have to ask someone about his/her group:

> I: Which group are you **in/on**?
>
> Person: I'm not **in/on** any group.

So should "in" be used or "on" ?

Comment: on a team, on the team and neither have to do with AmE. It's just English. Groups, in for sure. You cannot be "on" a group and this is easily googlable. "on a committee"

Comment: Strangely, the use of *both* prepositions together actually has some meaning—even though it wouldn't be common. *Which group are you* ***in on***? It would mean something like *Which group do you have inside information about?*

Answer (score 1):

Use "in".

"To be in a group" is the correct form, whether or not it's AmE. We usually don't say "to be on a group".

However, you can use "to be in/on a team". You should look up verbs that collocate with your nouns of choice.